# Define new parameter based on several responses in long dataset in R

Tags: r, if-statement, data-structures, conditional-statements, grouping

I have a dataset with multiple lines per patient with the following structure:

```
 A tibble: 15 x 3
   SubjectNo Question Answer
       <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1         1        1      0
 2         1        2      1
 3         1        3      0
 4         1        4      1
 5         1        5      0
 6         2        1      1
 7         2        2      1
 8         2        3      0
 9         2        4      0
10         2        5      1
11         3        1      1
12         3        2      0
13         3        3      0
14         3        4      0
15         3        5      1
```

The structure is identical per patient, so each patient has an input for all 5 questions. The answers can only be 0 or 1.
I want to create a new parameter per unique subject number which is based on the order of the "Answer" parameter.

Example:
if "Answer" is 00001, then new parameter is "combination 1"
if "Answer" is 00011, then new parameter is "combination 2" ect.

I have a basic idea about grouping the data by Subject number and then using an ifelse formula, but I did not succeed putting it into a working code.

Answer (score 0):

We may do a group by `SubjectNo`, `paste` the elements in 'Answer' to a single string, and use `match` to get the index after `sort`ing

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
 group_by(SubjectNo) %>%
 mutate(new = as.numeric(str_c(Answer, collapse = ""))) %>%
 ungroup %>% 
 mutate(new = match(new, sort(unique(new))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(SubjectNo = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Question = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), Answer = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 

"14", "15"))
```